# Authentication keeps asking for password

Tags: laravel, authentication

So my creating a Laravel custom authentication, and I'm in the stage of creating the login form, but it suddenly keeps asking to fill up the password, and I already did it, but nothing happens.

This is my Login form:

```
<form action="{{ route('auth.check') }}" class="log-form" method="post" value="{{ old('email') }}">

        @if(Session::get('fail'))
        <div class="alert-danger">
            {{ Session::get('fail') }}
        </div>
        @endif

        @csrf

            <div class="name">
                <label for="fname">Email Address</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""><br>
            </div>

            <span class="text-danger">
                @error('email') {{ $message }} @enderror
            </span>


            <div class="name">
                <label for="fname">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" id="pass" name="fname" value=""><br>
            </div>

            <span class="text-danger">
                @error('password') {{ $message }} @enderror
            </span>
            
            
            <br><br>


            <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="log-sub">

        </form>
```

And this is my controller:

```
 function check(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|min:6|max:16',
    ]);


    $userInfo = Admin::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();

    if($userInfo){
        return back()->with('fail', 'We do not recognize your email address');
    }
    else {
        if(Hash::check($request->password, $userInfo->passsword)){
            $request->session()->put('LoggedUser', $userInfo->id);
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }

        else {
            return back()->with('fail', 'Incorrect password');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think before you do anything else you learn the HTML basics... You have used the `for` attribute twice and linked it to `fname` even though that ID does not exist. This needs changing to `email` for the first instance and `pass` for the second. Not to mention there is a `type="email"` that is highly recommended to use in HTML5. Also, why are you setting a value on the form tag??

Comment: Why are you wanting to build your own auth system instead of using one of the first party Laravel ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem simply is with your input name. In the validation you expect to have an input named password however the password input is named as fname so the validation will always fail because password field is required.
So instead of :

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="fname" value="">
```

use :

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="password" value="">
```